# Select child element from parent data attributes value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this kind of html blocks:

```
<div data-target="TargeID" data-action="toggle" data-trigger="Yes">
    ...

    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="radio">
            <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_0" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl01$rbAnswer">
            Yes             
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label class="radio">
            <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_1" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl02$rbAnswer">
            No              
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label class="radio">
            <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_2" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl03$rbAnswer">
            maybe               
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to select every input inside elements with `data-action="toggle"`

and Im using this jQuery selector: `$('[data-action="toggleQuestions"] :input');`

but I need to select those input which `text` value is equal to the parent `data-trigger` value.

Is it possible directly with a selector?

Comment: Why does it need to be directly with a selector? You cant just use a `filter` call?

Comment: @Jamiec i was wondering if there were a more concise way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is too complex to put in to a single selector. Instead you can use `filter()` to find the `:input` elements, then match the `text()` of their parent `label` to the `data-trigger` value on the container. Try this:

```js
var $container = $('[data-action="toggle"]');
var $input = $container.find(':input').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('label').text().trim() == $container.data('trigger');
})

$input.prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-target="TargeID" data-action="toggle" data-trigger="Yes">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label class="radio">
        <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_0" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl01$rbAnswer">
        Yes             
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="radio">
        <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_1" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl02$rbAnswer">
        No              
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="radio">
        <input id="cpMainContent_ctl24_rptAnswers_rbAnswer_2" type="radio" name="cpMainContent_ctl24" value="ctl00$cpMainContent$ctl24$rptAnswers$ctl03$rbAnswer">
        maybe               
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that was the road i was trying but i hoped there were a selector syntax like ```$('[data-action="toggleQuestions"] :input:value=[data-trigger]')```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
$('[data-action="toggle"]').each(function() {
    var triggerValue = $(this).attr("data-trigger");

    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().text().trim() === triggerValue) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The trigger value is the text of the `label`. It's not the `value` of the radio as your code uses